# Why isn't shell expanding the braces in the shell script?

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying the following script for listing the archived files in my current directory.

```
#!bin/sh
for file in *.{zip,jar}
do
echo $file
done
```

which gives the output:

```
*.{zip,jar}
```

Why isn't shell expanding the braces?

Comment: Because `sh` is not `bash`? See [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following shellscript works for me

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.{png,jpg}; do echo $file; done
```

1. This brace expansion works in `bash`, but not in `sh`
2. `#!bin/sh` lacks a slash, should be `#!/bin/sh` to work correctly